# Calling async task class not working

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm sure I am doing something wrong, new to Android, I already have the URL stored in a string in a for loop, need to grab the image from that URL using AsyncTask. Quite new to Android so I am running into some issues. Any help is appreciated.

SecondClass.java

```
package edu.colum.iam.JSON;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondClass extends Activity {
private TextView first, second, third;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        first = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firsttv);
        second = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondtv);
        third = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirdtv);

        String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        System.out.println(id);

        String response = readBuilding(id.trim());
        System.out.println(response);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            if(jsonObj.length()>0)
            {
                String CourseName = jsonObj.getString("CourseName");
                String CourseNumber = jsonObj.getString("CourseNumber");
                String CourseDescription = jsonObj.getString("CourseDescription");
                JSONArray arrayOfImages = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Images");
                String theImage = arrayOfImages.get(0).toString(); //getting first image in the array and returning the link as a string


                int arrSize = arrayOfImages.length();

                List<String> urlOfImage = new ArrayList<String>(arrSize);

                first.setText("CourseName:- "+CourseName);
                second.setText("CourseNumber:- "+CourseNumber);
                third.setText("CourseDescription:- "+CourseDescription);
                for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfImages.length(); ++i)
                {
                    theImage = arrayOfImages.get(i).toString();
                    urlOfImage.add(theImage);
                    ImageDownloadTask(theImage);
                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public String readBuilding(String id)
    {
        return postJSON("http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course/"+id+"?json=True");

    }

    private String postJSON(String stringURL) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(stringURL);

        try {

            httpget.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

ImageDownloadTask.java

```
package edu.colum.iam.JSON;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    /** The url from where to download the image. */
    private String url;

    /** Reference to the view which should receive the image */
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageRef;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param imageView
     *            The ImageView which will receive the image.
     */
    public ImageDownloadTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageRef = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    /**
     * This function will be executed to download the image in a background
     * process.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ImageDownload", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This function will be called after the image download and attaches
     * the bitmap to the ImageView.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageRef != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageRef.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a library for image downloading? It might make your life a lot easier (some would say you are currently trying to re-invent the wheel). Picasso is my favourite: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: How would you rate Picasso against loopj? Will check that out as well!

Comment: I've not used loopj, but it appears to just be an HTTP client. Picasso handles the download of the image and the insertion into the ImageView fully, so it would potentially eliminate the need for a ton of code. It alsp automatically handles image caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downloading images by URL I recommend to use third part libraries. For example Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso).
To download image you just need to write this:

> Picasso.with(SecondClass.this).load(url).into(imageView);

Answer (score 1):

There might be more issues here (such as possibly accessing network on main thread?), but this `ImageDownloadTask(theImage);` won't actually execute your `AsyncTask`. It shouldn't even compile. You'd want something like `new ImageDownloadTask(theImage).execute();`